# UI Elements in a protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols

My app has about 6 interface builder based views that contain the same UI elements, and are initiated by the same ViewModel, but all of the views are different classes (some are UICollectionViewCell, some are UITableViewCell, and some of them are a part of a view in a UIViewController), they look completely different, with different constraints and overall different design.

I found out that there is a lot of code duplication for binding the UI elements with the ViewModel in each view, and I tried to find a way to clean up the code.

Because the app is **protocol-oriented**, I came up with the following solution:

```
protocol Common {
    var someTitleLabel: UILabel! { get set }
    var someImageView: UIImageView! { get set }
    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel?)
}

extension Common {
    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel?) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        someTitleLabel?.text = viewModel.title
        someImageView?.image = viewModel.image
}
```

and the implementation of each view:

```
class someClass: UICollectionViewCell, Common {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
```

```
cell.configure(viewModel: viewModel)
```

The good thing is that it works.

The bad thing is that I have never seen such implementation in any app I worked on.

So, the main questions are - is that a good practice for such problem?
Should I give up protocol oriented structure for this situation and use OOP?
What would be the best practice of making 'generic' interface builder views, configured by the same ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of inheritance to achieve same outcome.

```
YourBaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!

        func configure(viewModel: ViewModel?) {
            guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
            someTitleLabel?.text = viewModel.title
            someImageView?.image = viewModel.image
        }
}
```

And then connect to outlets to the base class for each xib file you have.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the obvious answer, as mentioned, the app is protocol oriented structured , and therefore I'm trying to avoid OOP structure. I'm looking for much deeper answer, or a discussion about modeling the UI with protocols, and if that's even a good practice.

Comment: In my opinion, its really great to have protocols in your application. However it doesn't necessarily mean that you should avoid OOP in your architecture.

Comment: I thought that i wrote it in the question, and I will now edit. the views are not necessarily a collectionViewCell, it can be also a tableViewCell or even a viewController.

Comment: Yes thats a good information. It's now not possible to implement with inheritance.

Comment: The problem with this approach is not having configure method implemented in your concrete classes

Answer (score 0):

Its better to give your concrete class a control over configure method

```
protocol Common {
    var someTitleLabel: UILabel! { get set }
    var someImageView: UIImageView! { get set }
    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel)

}

extension Common {
    func configureCommonProperties(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        someTitleLabel?.text = viewModel.title
        someImageView?.image = viewModel.image
    }
}

class someClass: UICollectionViewCell, Common {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!

    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        configureCommonProperties(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer twice. If there are two possible solutions, discuss them in a single answer. If you don't like your first answer (perhaps the OP changed the question), _edit_ the first answer.

Comment: @matt, if the solutions are different enough, it's ok to post them separately - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25210/277866

Comment: Yes they are two different approaches. So I decided to answer separately

Comment: @Cristik That's one opinion, and I don't agree with it. The problem is that this looks like an attempt to garner a double set of upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

YourBaseCell:

```
UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!

    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel?) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        someTitleLabel?.text = viewModel.title
        someImageView?.image = viewModel.image
    }
}
```

Instead of inheriting from Cell you can inherit from UIView and use this new class as a custom view when you build your cell ui that way there is no problem with Table vs Collection cells and it solves the "code duplication for binding the UI elements with the ViewModel"

you can do some thing like that:

```
CellContenierView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var someTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someImageView: UIImageView!

    func configure(viewModel: ViewModel?) {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        someTitleLabel?.text = viewModel.title
        someImageView?.image = viewModel.image
    }
}
```